# read data up to '\n'

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have an input file for my program that stores the values to use for two parameters.

```
# X parameter values to use
10 20 30 40
# Y parameter values to use
5
```

The number of the values are not fixed but is the client that choose how many values to use (in this example 4 for X and 1 for Y (could be 0 too)). If I do an

```
ifstream in("input.in");
int value;
in >> value >> value >> ...
```

the program don't stops at the end of the line and reads obviously also Y line for X values when the X line ends. How to stop reading at the end of the line? I want to read values untill in found the '\n'. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::string line;
std::getline(in, line);
```

Now you have the line as a string (*`#include <string>`*) and need to parse it. You can do it the same way as before by making use of `std::istringstream` (*`#include <sstream>`*).

```
std::istringstream iss(line);
while (iss >> value) // read until failure
{
    // process value
}
```